# Add header into gcloud create subscription push command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

How can I add a header Authorization when creating a push subscription using gcloud command. I've tried this

```
if [ $(gcloud pubsub subscriptions list --filter="name: subscriptions/${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}-my-subscription" 2>/dev/null | wc -l) = 0 ]; then
          gcloud pubsub subscriptions create ${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}-my-subscription \
            --topic ${TOPIC_PRODUCT_UPDATE} \
            --push-endpoint=${MY_API_URL}/products-update \
            --header=`Authorization: Bearer ${AUTHORIZED_API_KEY}`;
        fi
```

--header is not a recognized param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used access_token, gcloud command does not support params in header

```
--push-endpoint=${MY_API_URL}/products-update?access_token=${AUTHORIZED_API_KEY}
```

Comment: If that is the solution that worked for you, could you edit your answer and write it in english so other people can make use of it as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/create#--push-auth-service-account), you can authenticate when creating the pubsub subscription with a service account. This can be achieved using the following flag:

`--push-auth-service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`

Which will use the service account email provided as the identity for the generated Open ID Connect token for authenticated push.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to define specific headers. You can use pubsub identity as described by @bhito but you can't set an API KEY as you expected.

A workaround is to use a proxy, like [Endpoint (ESP)](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp) which identifies your pubsub identity and adds your API KEY header when it forward the request. But this will add some latencyies in your process (and additional cost)